# Custom javascript/jquery not working on angular view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to angular and have built a simple single page application with routing to other pages. For some reason though I cannot write custom jquery/javascript on my pages. I want to implement simple bootstrap functionality i.e. (pop-up boxes),but I have been unsuccessful. Ive installed bootstrap.js through nuget packager so it works fine just not the js part. When I tried creating a simple index.html page outside of my views directory, everything worked fine however this page breaks out my routing sequence. Any Ideas?

Comment: what errors you receive in your log is important, you should use a controller and when for example  your template loaded act for your jquery classic function initiation $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
            jQueryfunction1.init();
        });
I hope this makes sense for you

Comment: I get a couple warnings about errors regarding the basic html but thats it. As for that second part are you saying I have to incorporate my js functionality within my controller js page?

Comment: I want to use built in angulary/bootstrap dependencies so it would all have to be on a view. https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

Comment: No problem about angular-ui, but this is important when you are using angular views, to manipulate your code correctly use $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() { jQueryfunction1-2-3.init(); })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together). Also make sure you are not initializing multiple instances of js/jquery. Is your console showing you any errors?